# How to collect Criteria to filter SP list on from user in SPFx ACE

Tags: spfx, adaptive-cards, spfx-aces

I have an spfx ace that has a quick view which is populated from a SP List. The list has fields "Phone Number", "Carrier" and "Country". All works OK, but I really want the user to be able to filter by "Country". I have tried to to achieve this in the quick view by togglevisibility of elements based on choiceset, but that doesn't work as I cannot retrieve the state of the choiceset.

I am struggling to figure out how to collect the Country from the user that the list should be filtered on. Do I have to use multiple quickviews, first one to select the country and then pass that to the 2nd quickview, or is there an easier way?

Any samples out there that I could look at?
Thanks.